# Change a for loop into a while loop - Swift

Tags: swift, loops, for-loop, while-loop

How can I change this for loop into a while loop ?

```
 let op = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]

 for x in op {
   if display.text!.rangeOfString(x) != nil {
           y = x
           break
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just learn Control Flow form swift for better understanding : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html

Comment: You shouldn't.  If you need to do something for every item in an array, you should use a `for`-`in` loop.  Nothing else makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this to create a while loop that will let you do an action for each item in the array, provided it is 4 elements.

```
let op = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
var count: Int = 0
while (count < 4)
{
    print(op[count])
    //perform any action with op[count] in here.
    count += 1
}
```

Comment: `: Int` is unnecessary--that'd be `count`'s assumed type.  You probably want `while count < op.count` (particularly since the `while` loop would allow mutation of the array in the body).  And if the intent is to do more than one thing with `op[count]`, you should probably start by saving it into a variable scoped to the loop body.

Comment: Thanks, tis worked fine too!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you really must use a `while` loop, this would be the closest approach to correct:

```
let op = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
var opSequence = op.generate()

while let nextOp = opSequence.next() {
    print(nextOp)
    // do something with nextOp
}
```

It's pretty important to understand, however, that this is not really that much different for the `for`-`in` loop, as a `for`-`in` loop is effectively just syntactic sugar for the above code.

The `for`-`in` loop is cleaner and a lot closer to what someone would expect to see here.

We can also write a `while` loop that gives us both the index and the value, as such:

```
let op = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
var opSequence = op.enumerate().generate()

while let (index, nextOp) = opSequence.next() {
    print("At index \(index): \(nextOp)")
}
```

And you can apply this same set of code to any `CollectionType`.  But again, this is not really any different than what is happening under the covers of a `for`-`in` loop.  A `for`-`in` loop relies on this `generate()` method which returns an `IndexingGenerator`, which has a method `next()`.  The `next()` method returns an optional type of whatever the collection holds, and the `for`-`in` loop, much like this `while` loop does, calls `next()` per iteration, and so long as it got a non-`nil` value, it enters the loop body with that value.

The primary differences are the fact that the `for`-`in` loop doesn't leave you with a dangling variable (in this example, the `opSequence` variable) and the fact that the `for`-`in` loop is simply a lot more readable.